# Dynamics CRM - Replaced all 'Lead Source' options with new items that caused all records in the system to get updated

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

We wanted to tweak the options of the Lead Source field in the Leads entity. We removed the existing items by deleting them. And added in new items. This has caused all the records to get updated with new Lead Source items. There is a lot of mismatch between the old values and the new ones.

I am guessing the 'Value' field for the 'Lead Source' set references the 'Lead Source' field in the Leads entity. When the item corresponding to that value changed, the referenced record automatically got updated.

Do we have a way to recover the old items and replace them to their original state?

I want an easier way out so I don't have to ask my DBA to roll back changes to the CRM database.

Help appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a solution that contains Lead you could import the solution and overwrite the customizations.

If you do not have a recent solution containing the Lead entity you could export a solution from another CRM organization, import the solution, and then re-do the customizations to Lead.


You could also manually copy all the Lead Source option set values from another CRM organization.
There are only 10 so it is a 5 minute job.


These are the options, values start from 1 and proceed to 10:


[image]

Comment: This would help but unfortunately I have added 15 new items to the option set. I am not sure what their values are.

Comment: Add an item to the options in the same way that you did last time and take note of the value; make sure that you add the item through the same solution. You will be able to work out the value of the 15 if you know what order they were added in.

Comment: I did that before. Unfortunately, I did not make note of the values. So, when I replaced the option set items with new ones, the old items got replaced and now I have no way of knowing what value belonged to what item!

Comment: As far as I know you will only be able to recover the default values; unless you revert to a database restore.